# knockout validation message not displayed on nested object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a nested observable in my vm something like firstlevel().secondlevel() with secondlevel() observable having a validator attached to it;

I am using the following code to then validate

```
   var result = ko.validation.group(self, { deep: true });
                    if (!self.isValid()) {
                        result.showAllMessages(true);
```

The problem i have is that for some reason the validation works correct and isValid() is false, however showAllMessages(true) does not populate the validation spans. When i dig into the the result variable i can see the messages are there, just not populating the spans?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: how are you binding these messages in your mark-up?

Comment: Please post your html with your binding! Also if you can create a JSFiddle repro that would be also very helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @nemesv although my fiddle isnt working this is basically the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ganymede/xub3j/33/

Comment: The cdnjs version of the validation plugin has bug so you need to call `ko.validation.init()` but otherwise your code looks ok: http://jsfiddle.net/6SBgF/

Comment: @nemesv thanks for the jsfiddle guess im back to the drawing board.. i dont know why yours works and mine doenst :(

Comment: @nemesv - I have tried absolutely everything. the messages will not appear unless i move the observable within the object to the first level of the vm.

Comment: Because your code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6SBgF/ please try to extend this fiddle with your actual non working code to create a repro.

Comment: @nemesv: i thought i found the problem but not. Is there any way to debug the problem?